# Errors trying to publish precompiled ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my project running on localhost and production, however because of the slow first access of each view, I'm trying to publish it precompiled (Precompile during publishing > (Disabled) Allow precompiled site to be updatable).

I saw that the errors are all related to my ViewModel classes (which I repeat, they work correctly on localhost and on production without precompiling).

The type or namespace name 'ChangePasswordViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'ProjectName.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I already deleted the entire content of the `Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\` folder.

Comment: In the deployed folder, did you check to ensure the dll which contains your viewmodel classes are there?

Comment: The publish is set to Web Deploy, directly to the production server, however the process stops before the it starts copying the files.

Comment: On your local, can you delete the bin folder then rebuild and ensure it works. I want to confirm all is well on the local. And can you do a web deploy but to your local iis server and see what happens there.

Comment: I got the same problem after deleting the bin folder and rebuilding. Tried web deploy to local IIS and publishing to local folder. Considering that the errors are related to my View Model classes (under Project Root\ViewModel\ folder), will I have to move them to App_Code to make precompile work?

Comment: Open the csproj file of your asp mvc application and turn this flag on: <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews> by changing it to true. Then it will compile everything into your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes I'm posting the solution to my problem.

The ASP.Net MVC project template creates authentication classes on project root, then I moved these classes to an area and replaced the namespace.

Then the problem was that some Views didn't get the new namespace. After fixing the `@model` references, the publish feature worked.